# Flutter error: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..7, inclusive: 8 after list.add()

Tags: flutter

I get my data from API and also add my data to API. I faced this error when I add `people.add(resp[0]); in addPeople()`:

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..7, inclusive: 8

I add this `people.add(resp[0]);` because I want to show after I add the data. This is because after I add the data, the added data did not show.

Here is my code:

```
  List people;
  List selectedPeople = [];
  List checkBox = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void addPeople(name) async {
    http.Response response = await http.post(url, body: {'name': name});
    final resp = json.decode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      people.add(resp[0]);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
        actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
           icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline), 
           onPressed: () {
              _asyncInputDialog(context);
            }
          ),
        ]
      ),
      body: _buildListView(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListView() {
    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: people == null ? 0 : people.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(people[index]['name']),
          trailing: Checkbox(
            value: checkBox[index],
            onChanged: (value) {
              if (value) {
                setState(() {
                  checkBox[index] = true; selectedPeople.add(people[index]);
                });
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  checkBox[index] = false; selectedPeople.remove(people[index]);
                });
              }
            },
          ),
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {return Divider();},
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding people but not adding checkbox for it.

You have to add following line.

```
setState(() {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      people.add(resp[0]);
      checkBox.add(false);
    });
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, it still has the same error

Comment: can you add what you are getting in resp variable before adding?

Comment: this is my resp in addPeople(), [{id: 3, name: test}],  response from api